# Mouse pointer does not change appearance

Tags: 11.10, unity, mouse

I am using Oneiric with Unity installed in a netbook and in a desktop.
In both the machines I have this problem: when I click on a Quick-Launcher icon the mouse pointer, when the program is starting, does not change the appearance from the arrow to the "rotating clock" for telling me that the machine is working.

So, specially for the netbook, I have to wait much time before I could understand if it is really working or not.

May I do something to make it working like the previous releases?
(in 11.04 I used the Classical view)

Comment: The expectation is that the application should *always* launch and so no visual indication (like a mouse cursor change) is needed or appropriate. If you ever launch an app from the unity or unity-2d launcher and the app does not launch, that would be a bug that should be logged and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

it is a normal behavior i think.
with the unity launcher the mouse should not change. there are different ways to see if it is "working" or "loading".

- install `compizconfig settings manager` from the ubuntu software
  center
- launch the compiz config from dash
- go down and search for the `unity plugin`
- click on the experimental tab
- change the launch animation to `pulse until running` or other option
  you are comfortable with

now you can see the icon on the launcher blinking (sign it is loading) untill the application comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back to Gnome classic  (the version with the bars along the top and bottom) in Ubuntu 11.10, install the GNOME-Shell appilcation.